Constructor classes: why not mention the content's type?
Following on from this q about monad transformers ...
Before constructor classes were introduced [M.P.Jones 1993], Haskell class decls:

Must have a single parameter;
That parameter must be kind Type (aka * at the time).

The innovation was to allow the parameter to be kind Type -> Type (aka * -> *). This has the (well-known [**]) unfortunate consequence the instance decls can't talk about the 'content' type -- for example to constrain a Set's content to be in Ord. (Why) couldn't the class decl look like this:
class Functorb (f b)  where           -- not currently allowed in a class decl
  fmapb :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance (Ord b) => Functorb (Set b)  where
  fmapb f NilSet = NilSet
  fmapb f xs     = fromList (map f $ toList xs)

Note that signature for fmap is the same as Haskell's standard. This isn't using FlexibleInstances or overlapping instances or any of that stuff that came along much later in Haskell.
(Note also we don't need the Ord constraint on the 'incoming' Set's content type a: we're consuming it, not building anything from it.)
It'd require the class header to use only tyvars; and would still require a Kind system [paper's section 1.3].
Could you use a MultiParamTypeClass? (They'd been considered but not implemented as at 1993, I believe.) The paper (end of section 1.1) says:

Other attempts to define the map function, for example using multiple parameter type classes, have also failed for essentially the same reasons.


[reason appearing just above] the principal type of map j . map i ... the type is ambiguous (the type variable e does not appear to the right of the ⇒ symbol or in the assumptions).
[where e is the type of the intermediate result from map i/argument to map j.]

Addit: Implementing @Naïm Favier's suggestion from the comments, that compose isn't ambiguous according to GHC (8.10):
fmapb show . fmapb ((+ 0.5). fromIntegral)
:: (Show a1, Functorb f a1, Functorb f String, Fractional a1,
    Integral a2) =>
   f a2 -> f String

(Making sure both fmapbs are type-changing the 'content'.)
And produces the result expected, applied to a Data.Set of Ints.
Addit 2:
This works using type equality (~) (again GHC 8.10, and that compose gives the same type):
class Fmapb fb  where
  fmapb :: fb ~ f b => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
instance Ord b => Fmapb (Set b)  where
  fmapb f xs = fromList $ Prelude.map f (toList xs)

[Addit ends]
These days we might use a type family:
type family Constr (fb :: Type) :: (Type -> Type)  where
  Constr (f b) = f
type family CArg (fb :: Type) :: Type  where
  CArg (f b) = b

class Functorb fb  where
  fmapb :: (a -> CArg fb) -> ((Constr fb) a) -> fb

(But that's a fairly 'dumb' use of TF's.)
[**] There is for example the 'constrained-monad'. This looks rather scary. AFAICT it's designed that way so it can be used inside a do block -- via -XRebindableSyntax.

You can absolutely do what you want with multi-parameter type classes: https://play.haskell.org/saved/9TcNHD0i. It doesn't make a lot of sense categorically, but you can. For a more principled approach, see exofunctors.

Thanks. There's a comment about that in the 1993 paper. I'll add a note to the q.

Such a thing is expressible now with other features (like multi param classes), but it's very different from the standard Functor. It absolutely would not have made sense to have the syntax you suggest instead of constructor classes, only perhaps as an additional option for expressing different kinds of class. Part of the point of Functor is you can use fmap with an a -> b function in a context where you know nothing about a and b. Whereas you need to know more about b is to know whether the Functorb f b instance is usable. So it's not strictly more applicable.

It's exactly like how any polymorphic function "gains" in power by being universally applicable to any type, but "loses" in power by being unable to depend on any property of the type its working with. Sometimes you want that, sometimes you want the opposite. It's not an "unfortunate consequence", it's a useful feature in its own right (it merely isn't always useful, depending on what you are trying to do).

"Sometimes you want that [depending], sometimes you want the opposite. " You can avoid depending by merely not constraining the 'content' type(?) (Ok that might be theoretically less 'abstract'.) Does something go wrong in a do block? -- that is, if Functor, Monad were extended with the 'content' type? (It's so awkward that you can't mix them in  do syntax.)  Thanks.

@AntC A Functor class that only has f as a parameter cannot have any instances that need extra constraints on the "content" type; the lack of constraint is statically knowable purely from the class. Which is exactly why consumers of the class get the freedom to use fmap without knowing anything any the content type. A class like your Functorb requires consumers of the class to have more type knowledge in order to check whether there are any such constraints on the specific instance in use, even if no actual instances exist that do constrain the content type.


for example using multiple parameter type classes

Ah, re-reading that from the 1993 paper, I think it means without any 'Kind system'/all class params of Kind Type. Something like:
class Functorb ab fa fb  where
  fmapb ::    ab    ->  fa   ->  fb
-- not  :: (a -> b) -> (f a) -> (f b)

So no ability in the class decl to express the commonalities in the structure of the args and result; hence no ability in a compose to infer the type of intermediate results.
(This ambiguous intermediate observation is also made in the 2000 paper, from the same stable that brought Functional Dependencies. | ab fa -> fb, ab fb -> fa, fa fb -> ab)
The 'theoretical purity' from defining Functor/Monad without being able to mention the 'content' types is a plentiful source of debate. These abstract properties follow from 'Functor Laws' and being 'structure-preserving'. (Plenty of hits on Stackoverflow for those terms.)
How the IO Monad manages to be structure-preserving is ... emm ... non-obvious.
Specifically, Data.Set can't be a Functor because for the map f :: a -> b:

x ≠ y ⇏ f x ≠ f y -- f not necessarily uniqueness-preserving
x < y ⇏ f x < f y   -- f not necessarily order-preserving

OTOH Haskell doesn't follow a strict procedural semantics where we'd update a new value at the address in the structure-to-be-preserved. I'm happy to cop for the term 'degenerate Functor' if only I could handle Data.Set in do blocks.
There's a further complication I've seen mentioned:

Sometimes you want to constrain the incoming 'content' type [1.2]; or even
constrain both the incoming and outgoing 'content' type [1.3].

(Perhaps your map function is partial: some incoming values can't produce an output.) This gets us even further away from structure-preserving.

For what it's worth, you can use -XQualifiedDo with Data.Set. You might have to write a module yourself to use it with, but it would only be a couple lines of code.
